# Why am I getting Undefined instead of Null from a Form drop down list when I haven't selected anything?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

So, I have a basic page where I find() data from a collection in my Database and I created it using Node.js, express, MongoDB and ejs. I created a Form so that I can filter data from the rendered table and send it as filters to mongoDb. The form consists of 3 input types, 2 text types and 1 drop down along with a submit button.

My problem lies in the Drop down. When I select a value from the drop down and submit, I get the filtered result. But whenever I leave the drop down as it is and fill any other input field to filter with only those, I dont get back any Data.

Here is the code for my Drop down:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <select class="form-control" name="searchDept">
      <option selected disabled value="">Choose Department</option>
      <option value="Computer Science Engineering">Computer Science Engineering</option>
      <option value="Information Science Engineering">Information Science Engineering</option>
      <option value="Electrical & Electronics Engineering">Electrical & Electronics Engineering</option>
      <option value="Electronics and Communication Engineering">Electronics and Communication Engineering</option>
      <option value="Mechanical Engineering">Mechanical Engineering</option>
      <option value="Civil Engineering">Civil Engineering</option>
      <option value="Main Office">Main Office</option>
      <option value="Admission Office">Admission Office</option>
      <option value="Principal Office">Principal Office</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And in my app.js file, this is my get method:

```
    const searchName = req.body.searchName;
    const searchPhone = req.body.searchPhone;
    const searchDept = req.body.searchDept;

    if (searchName != "" && searchPhone != "" && searchDept != "") {
        
        var searchParameter = { $and: [{visitorName : searchName}, { $and: [{phone : searchPhone}, {deptOfVisit : searchDept}]}]}

    } else if (searchName != "" && searchPhone == "" && searchDept != "") {
        
        var searchParameter = { $and: [{visitorName : searchName}, {deptOfVisit : searchDept}]}

    } else if (searchName == "" && searchPhone != "" && searchDept != "") {
        
        var searchParameter = { $and: [{phone : searchPhone}, {deptOfVisit : searchDept}]}

    } else if (searchName != "" && searchPhone != "" && searchDept == "") {
        
        var searchParameter = { $and: [{visitorName : searchName}, {phone : searchPhone}]}

    } else if (searchName != "" && searchPhone == "" && searchDept == "") {
        
        var searchParameter =  {visitorName : searchName}

    } else if (searchName == "" && searchPhone == "" && searchDept != "") {

        var searchParameter =  {deptOfVisit : searchDept}
        
    } else if (searchName == "" && searchPhone != "" && searchDept == "") {

        var searchParameter =  {phone : searchPhone}
        
    } else {
        
        var searchParameter = {}

    }

    console.log(searchName);
    console.log(searchPhone);
    console.log(searchDept);
    console.log(searchParameter);

    var visitorSearch = Visitor.find(searchParameter);
```

Everything works fine when I select one of those options from the List and I am able to find the right Data and render it. But If I leave the Drop down without selecting anything, I get back no records.

So I tried console logging everything and when I did, I realised it's passing an "Undefined" value instead of null and is getting in the first if statement instead of the one where it should be null.

```
Test
12345
undefined
{ '$and': [ { visitorName: 'Test' }, { '$and': [Array] } ] }
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I be doing?

Comment: `null` and `""` are not the same thing, either.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Yeah I tried replacing "" with null but it just takes it as a String 'null'.

Comment: presumably, the values in `req.body` get set on a `change` event. If it doesn't change, they don't get set

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Oh I see! That makes sense, so do you know How can I work around this?

Comment: I tend to use `if (!!searchName  && !!searchPhone  && !!searchDept)`  The captures `null`,`""`, `0`,`false` and `undefined`

Comment: either that or set the initial values of `req.body` somewhere

Comment: @GarrGodfrey If I set the Inital values for it somewhere, won't that mean that I will never have it as Null. My project stores and retrieves Visitors' data to a college and if the guard needs to find a data entry with only the Visitor's Name or Phone number, that wouldn't be possible? Also which if statement specifically should I try replacing with the one you suggested?

Comment: that was an example of the first line. You can use `!searchDept` to match on an unset value, or `!!searchDept` to match any set value

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Ahh I see. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really found an answer to this but I found myself a work around. I assigned the 2nd option as Selected as that was working without me having to select it and changed the "Choose Department" option to "None". So as @GarrGodfrey said in the comments, req.body get set on a change. I dont know how it works with the second option without me changing it but anyway, If I dont want to search by Department, I click on the Drop Down and select None whose value is "" or null. And the Search happens perfectly.